# Search function never returns result though id exists in collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am working on nodejs and using mongoose, I am doing simple search of _id and function never return the result although id exists in the collection.

App.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var controllers = require('./controllers');
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 

 mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log('mongodb could not connect', err);
        return err;
    }
    console.log('Mongodb Connected ..!')
});
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

var port = process.env.PORT || 3030;



app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(session({
  secret: 'somekey',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

controllers.html(app);
controllers.api(app);

http.listen(port);
```

api.js file

```
var Game = require('../models/game');
app.post('/api/gotobingo75', jsonParser, function(req, res){


        Game.findById('59260b9a0067b336a0002237', function(err, g_data){
            console.log('here you are', g_data); // Never gets here No matter what
        });
    });
```

Game Collection Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


 var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var childSchema = new Schema({ user: 'string', pattern:'String'});


var gameSchema = new Schema({    
    room_id    : ObjectId,        
    users : [childSchema],  
    title     : String,
    text      : String,  
    deleted : Boolean,       
});

var collectionName = 'gameCol'
var Game = mongoose.model('game', gameSchema,collectionName);
module.exports = Game;
```

Strangely search starts to work sometimes but 90% of the time its not working. I have been searching for this issue for last 3 days but no luck. Please help

Comment: if you console.log(err) do you get anything?

Comment: Nope. Even tried try catch, I am using visual studio code to do step through debugging but it does not get any data.

Comment: An you can log the req.body inside the app.post()? I really dont see much that can go wrong here. The only thing i noticed when referencing the docs is that var Game = mongoose.model('game', gameSchema) should be the parameters. I cant find an example where the model takes 3 params.
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html

Comment: I saw somewhere that we can explicitly define actual name of collection in third param. even if I remove the 3rd param still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The FindById method takes an object as the first parameter. You should change yours like the following:

```
Game.findById({_id: ' your object id'} , some function(err, game){
 //some code 
})
```

The above code will search in your Game database and will return an object if it find one or an empty object if it doesn't.

Comment: I have tried that also but no luck.
Recently I check that in try catch I am getting this error message "No matching document found for id: someid". The find and save code is under a for loop

Also tried promise query.

Comment: What error do you get when using my suggested code?

Comment: I set ", { versionKey: false }" under schema and now its working fine. Is that Ok to do?

Comment: That's kinda a weird solve but sure as long as it works:)

Answer (score 0):

`findById` always takes value as type `ObjectId()` so always when you use `findById` it should be an `ObjectId()` not a `string` just convert the sting to `ObjectId` as below and try it will work.

```
var Object = new ObjectId('59260b9a0067b336a0002237');

Game.findById(object, function(err, g_data){
            console.log('here you are', g_data); // Never gets here No matter what
        });
```